# How to make 3d text with threejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, parcel

i'm try to add 3d text to my three js project, but still same error ['is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse. three js'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47GTf.png)

by the way im using parcel

```
import { FontLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js"
import { TextGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/TeapotGeometry.js"
```

```
const loader = new FontLoader();
loader.load("./font.json", (font) => {
  const textGeo = new TextGeometry('Hello', {
    font: font,
    size: 6,
    height: 2
  })

  const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xad4000}),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x5c2301})
  ])

  textMesh.castShadow = true
  textMesh.position.y += 15
  textMesh.position.z -= 40
  textMesh.position.x = -8
  textMesh.rotation.y -= 0.50

  scene.add(textMesh)
});
```

i tought i can look at 3D text, however it was wrong

Comment: According to the error message, you are trying to parse an HTML file as JSON. What does your `font.json` look like?

Comment: You’re importing `TextGeometry` from “geometries/TeapotGeometry.js". Why is that?

Comment: in my view it's problem with parcel, coz it's working well with react.

Comment: btw TeapotGeometry.js it's typo when i'm  paste to stackoverflow :)